# Push my local git repository to my OpenShift repository

Tags: git, openshift

I have trouble pushing my own project to my openshift source.

When i am in my local project master branch, i created a remote openshift repository with my openshift source:

```
git remote add openshift [ssh://....@nodejs-<app_name>.rhcloud.com/~/git/nodejs.git/
```

And then:

```
git push openshift master
```

And  I get:

```
To ssh://..../~/git/nodejs.git/
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://....nodejs.git/'

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I guess I need to pull first as the hint says but it will run over my source that I want to push to there

Answer (score 0):

Do a `git pull` first and the `git push`.

It is already saying -

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: git pull is making a mess it brings what there is in the openshift repository and add it to my code making a salad out of my source, i wrote it in the question

Comment: Any how you have to merge them. if the remote repo is ahead of local then it will not allow you to push.